# AWS ALB seems to be slower than CLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask

We are trying to attain performance improvement in our current API.

Which is in a EC2 container with Flask Restful API on NGINX reverse proxy with Gunicorn.

As tested with Chrome, It seems that TTFB is fluctuating from 200+ms to 500+ms.

We don't noticed this in CLB by the way.

Now anyone has made some configuration updates on this? would love to hear others thoughts on this

Comment: Can you add more details about your ALB setup ?  Are you using two availability zones as required  by ALB?

Comment: Yes, we have the same setting with both ALB and CLB has two availability zone.

Comment: What are you using as target groups for the ALB ?  Can you add some of the settings for these target groups ?

Comment: target groups using EC2 instances from the availability zones defined. So we have 4 instances having 2 instances per zone.

Comment: Have you tried looking at ALB metrics in Cloudwatch ?

Comment: We already did and didnt find any relevant information.